# ZonedDateTime in mybatis property map for insert to MS-SQL

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a class (call it class A) that contains as an attribute a sub-class (call it class B).

So

```
public class Request {
    private User user;
    private ZonedDateTime requestTime;
    //getters,setters
 }
public class User  {
   private Integer userID;
     //getters,setters
```

What I am trying to do is insert the request, or in code (assuming myUser and loggerMapper are already created):

```
Request myRequest = new Request(); 
myRequest.setuser(myUser);
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.now();
myRequest.setrequestTime(z);
loggerMapper.logRequest(myRequest);
```

Where I have an interface:

```
public interface loggerMapper {
    Boolean logRequest(Request myRequest);
}
```

And an xml mapper like such:

```
<insert id="logRequest" parameterType="map">
    insert into  Request(userID,requestTime)
    values (#{userID},#{requestTime})
</insert>
```

myBatis absolutley hates the ZonedDateTime, it just barfs about

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'requestTime'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this by using Joda Time and a custom typehandler.

Have a look here: http://noobjuggler.blogspot.com/2012/01/mybatis-spring-and-joda-datetime-solved.html